# Jenkins: special characters getting inserted in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, hudson, jenkins

I am executing a bash script inside. A command like this when executed

```
current_loc=/tmp/$BUILDTYPE
rm -rf $current_loc/*
[ -d $current_loc/ ] || mkdir -p $current_loc
```

Get replaced by

```
+ current_loc=$'/tmp/stage\r'
+ rm -rf '/tmp/stage
/*
'
+ '[' -d $'/tmp/stage\r/' ']'
+ mkdir -p $'/tmp/stage\r\r'
```

The `dollar` `quoting` and `\r` is creating havoc. How do I fix this?

Comment: i guess that you have '\r\n' as line delimiter in `current_loc=/tmp/$BUILDTYPE` and `...mkdir -p...` lines

Comment: Run `dos2unix` tool like this: `dos2unix myscript` and try

Answer (score 0):

You must replace '\r' symbol with command like

`BULDTYPE=$(echo $BULDTYPE | tr -d '\r');`

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to run a *BASH* script in Jenkins. Way #1 is to create a bash script and have Jenkins execute it as part of the build process. However, you can also type in a BASH script directly into Jenkins. Which way are you doing this?

My suspicion is that you've written your shell script using Notepad on Windows and then are executing it on Unix or on a Cygwin installation which is set to take Unix line endings. The `\r` you're seeing are there in your shell script itself.

You can reedit the script using a program editor, and then setting the line endings to Unix line endings. In VIM, you can do this by:

```
:set ff=unix
```

in the Command Mode.

If you use [Notepad++](http://notepadplusplus.org) on Windows (free download and open source), you select the `Edit->EOL Conversion->Unix` menu item. (Or you can use [Vim](http://www.vim.org))

You can run the `dos2unix` utility that most Unixes and Linux installations have, but I'd look over the script anyway in a program editor.

Do not use a non-program editor to edit a program. I've seen people use Winpad and forget to save the script as *Text*. Instead, they create a shell script in RTF format. RTF format makes Unix BASH shell sad.